# Is it possible to mask / crop a html element group dynamically?

Tags: html, css, svg, mask

Is there a way use javascript, css, canvas or svg to create an animated mask (can be just binary).

The closest I've come is using this:

```
var data = canvas.toDataURL();
$('#masked').css("-webkit-mask-image","url("+data+")");
```

But this only works in chrome and safari and is a bit buggy.

Is there a way of using css to draw a really simple triangular mask?

Comment: In Firefox [you can do it with SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content), but there's no straightforward cross browser solution that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

If its going to be dynamic you can do it with canvas, draw the path you want and fill it, by default canvas is transparent, so any of the parts not filled will show the element underneath. However if its going to be a static mask I suggest just using a png.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/whVK3/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;

// make a path for a triangle
ctx.beginPath();  
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,200);
ctx.lineTo(100,50);
ctx.lineTo(0,200);
ctx.lineTo(0,0);
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: This would work if I wanted to mask a canvas drawing, but I want to mask a group of html elements.

Comment: @pixelscript alright updated my answer, let me know if its what your looking for.

Comment: That's good if the background was going to be a flat colour, but the background is actually going to be more html elements. But I like your thinking!

Comment: Yeah with canvas you could draw an image to it ect. But idk, if its not going to be dynamic I would suggest just using a PNG with transparency for a mask.

Comment: It is going to be dynamic. I'm beginning to think I'll have to render the webpage in canvas then mask it. It's not going to be perfect though.